# How do you hold a reference to a NewExpression?

Tags: c#, expression-trees

I have this code:

```
public static Func<IDataReader, T> CreateBinder<T>() {

    NewExpression dataTransferObject = Expression.New(typeof(T).GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes)); 
    ParameterExpression dataReader = Expression.Parameter(typeof(IDataReader), "reader");

    IEnumerable<Expression> columnAssignments = typeof(T).GetProperties().Select(property => {
        MethodCallExpression columnData = Expression.Call(dataReader, dataReaderIndexer, new[] { Expression.Constant(property.Name) });
        MethodCallExpression setter = Expression.Call(dataTransferObject, property.SetMethod, new[] { Expression.Convert( columnData, property.PropertyType ) });

        return setter;
    });

    columnAssignments = columnAssignments.Concat(new Expression[] { dataTransferObject });
    BlockExpression assignmentBlock = Expression.Block(columnAssignments);

    Func<IDataReader, T> binder = Expression.Lambda<Func<IDataReader, T>>(assignmentBlock, new[] { dataReader }).Compile();

    return binder;
}
```

which long story short binds the properties on database row to `<T>`. The problem is that when I want to use/return `dataTransferObject`, it's instantiating a new copy each time. How do I just get the reference, without recreating the object?

Comment: You mean you want to reuse the same `binder` for any given type `T`?

Comment: Since `dataTransferObject` is a `NewExpression`, every time I use it, it's creating a new instance, rather than reusing the same instance. Like, when I call the setter method on it, it's doing `new T().Property` rather than reusing the previously instantiated object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to assign the `NewExpression` to a variable, and use that variable instead of the `NewExpression`.

```
var dataTransferObject = Expression.Variable(typeof(T), "dto");
var assignment = Expression.Assign(
                     dataTransferObject,
                     Expression.New(typeof(T).GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes)));
```

(add these expressions to the `BlockExpression`)

Comment: +1 but wouldn't you also need a return expression inside the block expression? Otherwise the lambda expression would not have a return value, right?

Comment: @p.s.w.g, IIRC the last expression in the block is used as the return value ; that's what the OP is already doing in his code.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I really wasn't sure. I know `Func<int, int> f = x => { 5; }` won't compile in C# because you'd need `return 5;`. I figured it would be the same when manually building the expression.

Comment: Since `Expression.Variable` creates a `ParameterExpression`, it wants me to add it to `Expression.Lambda`, which sort of breaks the Delegate signature.

Comment: @sircodesalot, no, you shouldn't add it to `Expression.Lambda`. It's a local variable, not a parameter, even though the type is `ParameterExpression` (there isn't a `VariableExpression` type)

Comment: @sircodesalot I think you add that to the `BlockExpression` instead. See [this override](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd630287.aspx).

Comment: @p.s.w.g, actually I didn't find an explicit mention of this in the documentation, but it is mentioned in a comment in the example for the [BlockExpression class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.blockexpression.aspx).

Comment: Exception at `Expression.Lambda` because a parameter is missing. Unless I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: @sircodesalot You might need to add your new variable *and* `dataReader` parameter as parameters to the `BlockExpression`.

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend using member intialization / binding expressions rather than a series of setters:

```
public static Func<IDataReader, T> CreateBinder<T>() 
{
    NewExpression dataTransferObject = Expression.New(typeof(T).GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes)); 
    ParameterExpression dataReader = Expression.Parameter(typeof(IDataReader), "reader");

    IEnumerable<MemberBinding > bindings = typeof(T).GetProperties().Select(property => {
        MethodCallExpression columnData = Expression.Call(dataReader, dataReaderIndexer, new[] { Expression.Constant(property.Name) });
        MemberBinding binding = Expression.Binding(property, Expression.Convert( columnData, property.PropertyType));

        return binding;
    });

    Expression init = Expression.MemberInit(dataTransferObject, bindings);

    Func<IDataReader, T> binder = Expression.Lambda<Func<IDataReader, T>>(init, new[] { dataReader }).Compile();

    return binder;
}
```

Comment: I agree, it's much cleaner. I was so focused on solving the problem as stated by the OP that I didn't even think of this...

Comment: Yeah, doesn't answer the initial question but works like a charm. I'll definitely use this. (Be cool to get the answer too though, heh)